# Checkbox doesn't change after clicking React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I need to update options so that later `useCallback` will process it, but when I click on the `checkbox`, nothing changes.
But if you comment out `setOptions`, then the `checkbox` changes

```js
  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    s22: {value: 'TRUE', s: 22},
    s23: {value: 'TRUE', s: 23},
    s24: {value: 'TRUE', s: 24}
  })
```

```js
  const changeFilter = event => {
    setOptions({ ...options, [event.target.name]: {
        value: event.target.checked.toString().toUpperCase(),
        s: event.target.value
      }
    })
  }
```

```html
              <div id="filter">
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="s22" type="checkbox" value="22" onChange={changeFilter} />
                    <span>УК</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="s23" type="checkbox" value="23" onChange={changeFilter} />
                    <span>ФК</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="s24" type="checkbox" value="24" onChange={changeFilter} />
                    <span>ФТ</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
              </div>
```

Found similar questions but there was a problem with `preventDefault`

Full code

```js
import React, {useCallback, useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {useHttp} from '../hooks/http.hook'
import {AuthContext} from '../context/AuthContext'
import {Loader} from '../components/Loader'

export const TreePage = () => {
  const [tree, setTree] = useState([])

  const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    s22: {value: 'TRUE', s: 22},
    s23: {value: 'TRUE', s: 23},
    s24: {value: 'TRUE', s: 24}
  })

  const {loading, request} = useHttp()
  const {token} = useContext(AuthContext)

  const fetchTree = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const fetched = await request('/api/tree', 'GET', options, {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      })
      setTree(fetched)
    } catch (e) {}
  }, [token, request, options])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTree()
  }, [fetchTree])

  useEffect(() => {
    var zoom = 1;
    var zoomStep = 0.1;
    document.getElementById("zoomIn").addEventListener("click",function(){
      zoom += zoomStep; document.getElementById("zoomtext").style.transform = "scale("+zoom+")";
    });
    document.getElementById("zoomOut").addEventListener("click",function(){
      if(zoom > zoomStep){
        zoom -= zoomStep;
        document.getElementById("zoomtext").style.transform = "scale("+zoom+")";
      }
    });
  })

  const changeFilter = event => {
    setOptions({ ...options, [event.target.name]: {
        value: event.target.checked.toString().toUpperCase(),
        s: event.target.value
      }
    })
  }

  if (loading) {
    return <Loader/>
  }

  return (
    <>
      {!loading &&
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col s6 offset-s3">
              <div id="filter">
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="s22" type="checkbox" value="22" onChange={changeFilter} />
                    <span>УК</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="s23" type="checkbox" value="23" onChange={changeFilter} />
                    <span>ФК</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <label>
                    <input name="s24" type="checkbox" value="24" onChange={changeFilter} />
                    <span>ФТ</span>
                  </label>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: tree}}></div>
            </div>
          </div>
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's working fine in the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sky-t0zyv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hi, it looks like you're currently using snippets, but most of them are not runnable - can you please update your code so that it includes one snippet which is runnable and reproduces your issue? You can see this link of how to create one for React: [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537)

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera added full code

Comment: @NickParsons I am using 16.12.0. This version is not on the site

Comment: @VladislavSokolov You can change the version manually, see the heading **Notes:** from the link. But you've added a lot more code since my last comment and it seems like you have additional files that export values. For that, you might find it easier to make a codesandbox like Amila has done